# max average value in MySql

Tags: mysql, sql, max, average

How to get the maximum from averages values in MySQL? The following query returns average values of amounts from table orders grouped by customers.

```
SELECT AVG(amount)
FROM orders
GROUP BY cust;
```

I want to receive a maximum value from average values using a single query with aggregate functions. Using ORDER BY ... DESC LIMIT  1 surely works, but what I am interested in is getting the maximum average value using aggregate functions solely. Is it possible at all? Thanks

Answer (score 6):

```
select max(avg_value)
from 
(
  SELECT AVG(amount) avg_value FROM orders GROUP BY cust
) tmp
```

Comment: Thank you, that works. Not possible to avoid aliases, though?

Comment: This works. But, I do not understand the need for `tmp` here.

Comment: @jay: `SELECT AVG(amount) avg_value FROM orders GROUP BY cust` is a subquery. You need to name subqueries. I chose `tmp` as name but you can use any name you like.

Answer (score 3):

I would do this with `order by` and `limit`:

```
SELECT AVG(o.amount) as avg_value
FROM orders o
GROUP BY cust
ORDER BY avg_value DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

This allows you to get the `cust` for the maximum as well.

Comment: I think this is the better answer.